# Is it possible to dynamically create a Google Form dropdown list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

For example, if the number `4` is entered in a certain cell in a spreadsheet, I would like to create a drop-down list with `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` in Google Form. Can it be operated?

I have created the code so far,

```
function setForm() {
  const sp = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetId");
  const sheet = sp.getSheetByName('sheet');
  const form = FormApp.openById("formId");
  // The number `4` is entered in cell A1
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var item = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)[0];
  var list = item.asListItem();
  list.clearOption();
  var choices = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= cellValue; i++) {
    choices.push(list.createChoice(i.toString()));
  }
  list.setChoiceValues(choices);
}
```

I expected the lists `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` to be created, but only the list `1` is created.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. If you want to create a question in a Google Form using the cell value of Google Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script, I think that the answer to your question of `Can it be operated?` is yes. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Now, I noticed your updated question. I thought that the method "clearOption()" is not included in Class ListItem. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item) But, you say `I expected the lists 1, 2, 3, 4 to be created, but only the list 1 is created.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. But, if you want to modify your showing script, please remove `list.clearOption();` and modify `list.setChoiceValues(choices);` to `list.setChoices(choices);`. By this, when `cellValue` is 4, the numbers 1 to 4 are put into the LIST item.

Comment: Could you please respond as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Also, even if you delete `list.clearOption()`, nothing changes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted an answer. Please confirm it. About `Also, even if you delete list.clearOption(), nothing changes.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate it. But, please confirm my answer and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- The method "clearOption()" is not included in Class ListItem. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item) If you want to modify your showing script, please remove `list.clearOption();`.
- And, please modify `list.setChoiceValues(choices);` to `list.setChoices(choices);`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function setForm() {
  const sp = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetId");
  const sheet = sp.getSheetByName('sheet');
  const form = FormApp.openById("formId");
  // The number `4` is entered in cell A1
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var item = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)[0];
  
  // --- I modified the below script.
  if (!item) { // added
    console.log("No LIST items.");
    return;
  }
  var list = item.asListItem();
  // list.clearOption(); // removed
  var choices = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= cellValue; i++) {
    choices.push(list.createChoice(i.toString()));
  }
  list.setChoices(choices); // Modified
}
```

or, I think that you can also use `setChoiceValues` as follows.

```js
function setForm() {
  const sp = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetId");
  const sheet = sp.getSheetByName('sheet');
  const form = FormApp.openById("formId");
  // The number `4` is entered in cell A1
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var item = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)[0];
  
  // --- I modified the below script.
  if (!item) { // added
    console.log("No LIST items.");
    return;
  }
  var list = item.asListItem();
  // list.clearOption(); // removed
  var choices = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= cellValue; i++) {
    choices.push(i); // Modified
  }
  list.setChoiceValues(choices); // Modified
}
```

- In this modification, when `cellValue` is 4 and `form` has LIST items, the 1st LIST item is updated by the numbers 1 to 4.
- If the LIST items are not included in `form`, you can see "No LIST items." in the log.

#### References:

- [Class ListItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item)
- [setChoices(choices)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item?hl=ja#setchoiceschoices)
- [setChoiceValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item?hl=ja#setchoicevaluesvalues)

Answer (score -1):

Create one or more dropdown lists by passing an array of question titles and list lengths to below function

```
function createLists(arr = [["one",5],["two",5],["Three",5],["four",5],["five",5]]) {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const items = form.getItems();
  items.forEach((itm, i) => {
    form.deleteItem(itm)
  })
  const qs = arr.map((r,i) => {
    let itm = form.addListItem();
    itm.setChoiceValues([...Array.from(new Array(r[1]).keys(), x => x + 1)]);
    itm.setTitle(r[[0]])
    return [i + 1, itm.getType(), itm.getTitle(), itm.getChoices().map(c => c.getValue()).join(',')]
  });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(qs));
}
```